# Git Error: Author identity unknown, Please tell me who you are

Tags: git, github

I keep getting the quoted error below anytime I try to commit on R studio

```
>>> git commit -F C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpARw5ml/git-commit-message-cb424997c45.txt
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'DELL@SIMPLY-COMPLEX403.(none)')
```

I was expecting a commit to happen so I could proceed to push

Comment: Did you try running the suggested commands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score 0):

I've heard this problem happening before, it may occur on this situations:

## 1.If You're Using Git Desktop

As Described in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003519/github-desktop-author-identity-unknown), Github Desktop Does Strange and requires you to set the settings manually in [app setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71283856/12233087)

## 2.There something wrong with your creds

Make sure the email and username are correct

## 3.There something wrong on your computer

Try setting them as a global variable like this:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="you@email.com" && GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Your Name" && git commit
```

Or, you can edit your ~/.gitconfig file directly. Look and see if there's a section for [user] with the relevant information. For example:

```
[user]
    name = Bob Gilmore
    email = me@mydomain.com
```

(There's no space in front of the [user], and single tabs in front of the name and email labels)

If it doesn't have those set properly, just go ahead and edit the .gitconfig file by hand.

Here's Some similar problems like yours that maybe help:
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283915/git-author-unknown)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685337/git-commit-author-doesnt-work-when-global-not-set)